# Match records using BigQuery SQL syntax

Tags: google-bigquery

My table contains some identifiers, call them ID1 and ID2 and the records look like this:

```
ID1   ID2
01    1
01    1
01    2
01    2
01    2
02    2
02    2
02    3
02    3
02    3
...
03    4
04    5
05    6
06    7
```

Because I can link `ID2 = 3` to `ID2 = 2` via `ID1 = 02` and then `ID1 = 02` to `ID2 = 01` via `ID2 = 2` in the first part of the example table, I know that that's a single entity that I'm interested in.

Is it possible to create a compound key from ID1, that would indicate that this is a single entity like:

```
ID1   ID2   ID_comp
01    1     01_02
01    1     01_02
01    2     01_02
01    2     01_02
01    2     01_02
02    2     01_02
02    2     01_02
02    3     01_02
02    3     01_02
02    3     01_02
03    4     03
04    5     04
05    6     05
06    7     06
```

This is just an example. There could be even longer sequences with multiple identifiers in both ID1 and ID2. Also note that some sequences of ID1 are directly mapped to ID2, like 03, 04, 05, 06. Both ID1 and ID2 are globally unique strings, but for simplicity I used numbers here. There's also a timestamp column by which the records can be sorted.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and using BQ scripting features

```
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE buckets AS 
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id2 ORDER BY id2) arr 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id1;

LOOP
  SET rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM buckets);
  SET run_away_stop = run_away_stop + 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE buckets AS
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr) arr FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr
    FROM (
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr1) arr1, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) arr    
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.arr arr1, t2.arr arr2, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr 
        FROM buckets t1, buckets t2 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) > 0
      ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr1)
    )
  ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr);

  IF (rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM buckets) AND run_away_stop > 1) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT id1, id2, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t.arr as id ORDER BY id), '_') ID_comp
FROM (
  SELECT id1, id2, ARRAY_AGG(id1) OVER(PARTITION BY grp) arr 
  FROM input 
  JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() grp, arr FROM buckets) 
  ON id2 IN UNNEST(arr) 
) t
-- ORDER BY id1, id2;
```

If to apply above script to sample data from your question - the output is

[image]

Note: to see above result you will need to click on <kbd>VIEW RESULTS</kbd> button for the last statement in the script - that will look similar to below after you run the script

[image]

Also note - you can control convergence of loop by adjusting `run_away_stop > 10` - as you can see now just 10 iterations allowed  - you can increase it as needed

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! this is really helpful.